# Post tweets in twitter using twitter api

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter

I want to post tweets using twitter api in VB 
using following code

```
Dim oauth_token = "aaa-1223d5fd1vfd5v1"
Dim oauth_token_secret = "asd23asd23adv534d3v13d54bs4v3dzb"
Dim oauth_consumer_key = "651sd313d4"
Dim oauth_consumer_secret = "dcs53sd123131fvb53215cv21321dv31dv3d1vsadf"

'==========================

Dim strURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

Dim oauth_version As String = "1.0"
Dim oauth_signature_method As String = "HMAC-SHA1"
Dim oauth_nonce As String = Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))

Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
Dim oauth_timestamp As String = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()

Dim oauth_signature As String = GeneraOAuthSignature(strURL, _
                                    oauth_nonce, _
                                    oauth_signature_method, _
                                    oauth_timestamp, _
                                    oauth_version)

Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_nonce=""{0}"", oauth_signature_method=""{1}"", oauth_timestamp=""{2}"", oauth_consumer_key=""{3}"", oauth_token=""{4}"", oauth_signature=""{5}"", oauth_version=""{6}"""
Dim strText As String = "@PramodNDS MyTweet"
Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), _
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version))

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

Dim req As WebRequest
Dim res As HttpWebResponse
Dim streamReader As StreamReader
Dim contenidoRespuesta As String = ""
Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")

req = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
req.Timeout = -1
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)

res = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

'==========================

streamReader = New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), encode)
While True
    contenidoRespuesta = streamReader.ReadLine()
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(contenidoRespuesta) Then
        InsertFacebookFeeds(contenidoRespuesta)
        Exit While
    End If

End While

'==========================

'Abort is needed or streamReader.Close() will hang
req.Abort()
streamReader.Close()
streamReader = Nothing
res.Close()
res = Nothing
```

How can I use this code post tweet for a particular tweet id or screen_name.

I have tried following code

```
objTwitter = New TwitterVB2.TwitterOAuth("jcLWDSpR587E0jIVtcmbcg", "VhgnHiITdBetYNDhMxJ29ObptqLWdGvraKG6qb4N6uY", "2325327612-MCOa5ZfhJC95LqoKcmflkoOBFh70wbq66g0Gwax", "MmBRZKscHJWnzb7Pn4Up2j0YeHCtYucV8DIiAOWhtrUvg")

 If strStatusMessage.Length < 140 Then
                        strStatusMessage = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(strStatusMessage)
                        strStatusMessage = strStatusMessage.Replace("*", "%2A").Replace("+", "%20")
                        Dim urii As Uri = New Uri(String.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status={0}", strStatusMessage))
                        Dim signature As String = objTwitter.GenerateSignature(urii, "01dbDUsbNvfcMHFjlXCJbw", "DCwZbwQ9kxEMBZ9geqYuNLGxnIWR6JHv0yfckPX14", authtoken, tokensecret, OAuth.Method.POST, objTwitter.GenerateTimeStamp(), objTwitter.GenerateNonce(), outsigurl, outsigpar, DBNull.Value.ToString, "")
                        xml = objTwitter.OAuthWebRequest(OAuth.Method.POST, outsigurl, outsigpar)
  End If
```

It giving an exception of TwitterAPI.

Any Help and suggestion will be useful.

Comment: @chrfin plz check updated code.. i have added changes.

Comment: Can you also post the exception?

Comment: @chrfin  Here is the one: "Exception of type 'TwitterAPIException' was thrown." I get this  in xml = objTwitter.OAuthWebRequest(OAuth.Method.POST, outsigurl, outsigpar) statement.

Comment: Is there no error message or so in the exception (or inner exception)?

Comment: @chrfin InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at TwitterVB2.TwitterOAuth.WebRequest(Method RequestMethod, String Url, String PostData) in D:\temp\TwitterVB-master\TwitterVB-master\TwitterVB2\TwitterOAuth.vb:line 392
       InnerException: